# What formula should I used to determine a value based on given input?

Tags: javascript, math

I think this is more like Math question rather than programming but since I'm writing Javascript, hope it is forgivable.

I receive user input, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

```
if 1, then output is 9

if 2, then output is 99

if 3, then output is 999
```

So basically input represent number of digit.

I admit that **I really suck at Math**. Tried to break this piece down to some kind of fomula
like 9 * 10 + 9 etc hoping I find some kind of Math approach to this problem but my brain corrupts.

I could do this by String concatenation way:

```
var userInput = 3;
var output = "";

for(var i=0; i<userInput; i++) {
    userInput = userInput + "9";
}

console.log(userInput); //now this should have string "999"

return parseInt(userInput); //return as integer 999;
```

while above works, I think it is really... not cool.

Could anyone show me if I can do this using Mathematical way?

Comment: Or `parseInt("99999".substring(0, userInput))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
output = Math.pow(10,userInput)-1;
```

That could work. Or:

```
output = new Array(userInput+1).join("9");
```

Although that's probably less efficient.

Comment: I think this is first time for me to use pow(). Only time I use Math api was for random.. thanks for the formula.

Answer (score 1):

[Math.pow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp) should do it:

```
Math.pow(10, userInput) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function nines(n) {
    var s = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s = s * 10 + 9;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Of course if you want a numeric version you'll be limited by the maximum size of a number (if I remember correctly JavaScript generally uses floats)